# How can I use a wildcard to match just files, not directories?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, wildcards

I have a folder called `home/homeLife`

I have a file called home1 home2 and home3 stored in /home

I want to move all files that start with `home*` to `home/homeLife/.`.

I typed

```
mv home* /home/homeLife
cannot move homeLife into subdirectory of itself
```

My question: How can I exclude directories?

Comment: Do you have a file called `home1 home2 and home3` or files called `home1, home2, home3`?

Comment: I gave an answer below to solve your task. The question to exclude directories is a bit less simple; I propose to use the `find -type f` command. (I'll provide details on request if necessary.)

Comment: regardless of the error message, your command should have succeed; it skipped the directory `homeLife`, because, at it says, it cannot move `homeLife` into itself.

Comment: heemay- No. I just made them with touch. I am working on a book called The Linux Command Line. They are empty files. Sometimes I just make up random tasks to learn things.

Comment: Hmm... i did not check yet if it, in fact did perform the move. Ill look immediately.

Janis. Yes. I would like more details. I am all about understanding Linux. Thank you for the command find -type f

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `zsh`, use glob qualifiers:

```
mv home*(.) dst
```

moves only *regular* files.

While

```
mv home*(^/) dst
```

moves files of any type *except* directories.

```
mv home*(^-/) dst
```

would also exclude symlinks to directories.

Comment: echo $SHELL shows zsh... I didn't realize I was using that. (NEWB). Anyway your commands are perfect. I deleted all files in a current working dir with # rm *(.)  thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

You can use find. The following should work.

```
find . -name home\* -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} /home/homeLife/. \;
```

Comment: I am curious to what the "\\*" is for? Why not just "home*" ?

Comment: In my example above, I am using '\' to avoid shell interpreting the wildcard. Quoting your wildcard like "home*" will work as well.

Comment: The `-maxdepth 1` option needs to come first, otherwise `find` will issue a warning.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bash extended globs:

```
shopt -s extglob                ## activate extglogs if not yet done
mv  home!(*Life) homeLife/      ## !(p1|...) = anything except one of the patt
```

Answer (score 2):

You're close already. To move your files `home1`, `home2`, `home3` use the globbing pattern `home?`.

```
mv home? /home/homeLife/
```

The `?` denotes any single character, while the `*` denotes any amount of characters (including none).

Comment: One point, if the file name really is `home1 home2 and home3` then you better use `mv home?* /home/homeLife/` ..this will work for both circumstances..

Comment: heemayl, that will not address the issue since your pattern will also match `homeLife` which was the one to avoid with the globbing expression.

Comment: my bad..did not see it closely.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Portably you can prune your glob match list:

```
set --; cd /home
for f in ./home*
do  [ ! -L "$f" ] && 
      [ -f "$f" ] && 
      set "$@" "$f"
done
[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || mv "$@" ./homeLife
```

Comment: +1 for portability (there are a lot of very old systems out there!)

Comment: Note that it moves regular files and symlinks to regular files.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - is that what you were talking about? Weird that `mv` doesn't seem to have any `-LHP` switches spec'd.

Comment: `[ -f "$f" ]` of `[ ! -d "$f" ]` were possibly fine for the OP. It's just worth _noting_ that those tests (as opposed to `find`'s `-type` or `zsh`'s `*(.)`, `*(^/)` for instance) look at the type after resolving symlinks. `mv` renames directory entries, `-LHP` would not be relevant for it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if you had only 3 files, you could just do

```
 mv home1 home2 home3 homeLife
```

Sometimes it is easier to do things manually than read the documentation.  If you really had a large number of files named `home*`, then one trick that I use (that is now part of bash) is to expand all the glob matches and then manually delete the matches I don't want.  To expand a glob, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> after you type the glob expression. It will expand on the command line, and then you manually fix it.

For example, in my directory, I have a lot of "test" files and I want to cat all of them *besides `test2`* to a new file:

```
cat test*
```

Now type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd>, and it expands to

```
cat test test10 test11 test12 test13 test14 test15 test16 test17 test2 test20 test21 test22 test23 test24 test25 test26 test27 test28 test29 test3 test30 test31 test32 test33 test34 test35 test36 test37 test38 test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9 testa testb testbuild testc testd teste testf
```

Then cursor back and remove `test2` with 5 backspaces, and then add `> test_all` to the end of the command line.

```
cat test test10 test11 test12 test13 test14 test15 test16 test17 test20 test21 test22 test23 test24 test25 test26 test27 test28 test29 test3 test30 test31 test32 test33 test34 test35 test36 test37 test38 test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9 testa testb testbuild testc testd teste testf > test_all
```

There are a bunch of other features of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, but this is the only one I remember.